# Why is my instance counter display 0 in this Python code?

Tags: python, debugging, class

I made a simple code to demonstrate and understand classes - however when I run this, my lists show that they are empty, containing "None" values instead of the strings that the user enters as names.

```
#Static methods do not require the object to be initiated. Can be remotely accessed from outside the function .

#Counting critters and remote access.

class Orc (object):

    total = 0       

    def get_score (self):
        print "The number of orcs the orc factory has made is",Orc.total   

    def __init__ (self):
        Orc.total += 1
        name =  raw_input ("I am a critter by the name of:\n")


#Creating 10 Orcs 


list = []

for i in range (4):    list[i] = list.append(Orc.get_score(Orc()))  

print "You have created 4 Orcs!" print "The name of your first orc is",list[0] print "The name of your fourth orc is", list[3]
```

Comment: Please, please, never name a list "list" in python.

Comment: Also, read a tutorial on classes in Python. You need to get your syntax straight.

Comment: -1, you could have at least read the documentation on the list-object. `append` does already append something to the list, no need to set it.

Comment: @Louis93 Please change the question title to reflect the actual issue - the problem has *nothing* to do with understanding classes.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: I don't think  it deserve -1, it's obviously somebody who doesn't know what is doing, is alone to figure it out and needs help. It's hard to ask the proper question when you don't really know the problem.

Comment: @e-satis: Perhaps, but that's no excuse for your answer below…

Comment: It's funny how aggressive a less than 4000 rep user can be nowaday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code. First in the way you use lists. Second, in the way you call methods on your objects. The combination of errors explains why you have a list of `None` at the end.

#### List name

```
list = []
```

Don't name a list `list`. It is already the name of, well..., the list class, i.e. in Python you can do `my_list = []` or `my_list = list()` with the exact same effect.

You want to call your list something meaningful, like `orc_list`

#### List Insertion

```
for i in range (4):
    orc_list[i] = orc_list.append(...)
```

`orc_list.append` does what it says: it appends an element to the given list. However, it does **not** return anything. So what your code is doing is

1. taking an empty list
2. setting `i` to 0
3. inserting what you pass to `append` at the end of the list
4. inserting `None` at index `i` and thus overriding what you did in 3.
5. incrementing `i`
6. going back to 3.

You want to simply use `orc_list.append(...)`

#### Method Call

```
Orc.get_score(Orc())
```

I imagine you are getting confused by the `self` argument. In a class, Python will automatically pass the instance you are working on as the `self` argument. You don't need to provide that argument.

You want to write

```
Orc().get_score()
```

This creates an `Orc` object, and then calls `get_score` on it. Python 'injects' the `Orc` instance you have created into `get_score` for you.

#### Method Return

We're now down to

```
orc_list.append(Orc().get_score())
```

which is equivalent to

```
score = Orc().get_score()
orc_list.append(score)
```

The problem is that there is no `return` statement in `get_score`. This means that python will return `None` when you call that method. Which means that you are appending `None` to your list.

You want to have

```
def get_score(self):
    print "The number of orcs the orc factory has made is", Orc.total
    return Orc.total
```

#### Static behaviour

If you really wanted to have a method not bound to an instance of the `Orc` class, you could use either a [class method](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) or a [static method](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

In your case, you do not need to do anything to the class object, so your choice would be to use a static method.

You would declare

```
@staticmethod
def get_score():
    print "The number of orcs the orc factory has made is", Orc.total
```

You would then call that method using `Orc.get_score()`

Comment: Good answer, but nowhere does it mention that using `Orc.get_score(Orc())` (or `Orc().get_score()` for that matter) also has the undesirable side-effect of causing the `Orc.total` class attribute to be incremented and therefore throws the count off.

Comment: @Martineau: instead of criticizing everyone else anwser, what about writing one that would match your standards ?

Comment: @rodrigue: +1 for the step by step explanation.

Comment: @martineau I didn't see it as an *undesirable* side effect. I understood that it was exactly what @Louis93 was trying to do: count the number of instances that are created.

Comment: @Rodrigue: Perhaps, but I suspect the side-effect would be unwanted because an `Orc` instance is being created just to call its method, so even though it is immediately discarded, it's being counted.

Comment: @e-satis: I haven't only criticized answers. The first thing in my initial comment for this one was praise and I upvoted it. True, I did find fault in your preliminary response, and am glad to see you've taken the time to edit and improve it. Frankly I was dismayed and somewhat surprised that someone with as *high* a rep as you would post something the way it first appeared.

Answer (score 5):

To define a class method in Python, use `classethod` decorator and call the first parameter `cls`

```
class Orc(object):

    total = 0       

    @classmethod # this will make the method a class method
    def get_score (cls): # convention is then to call the 1st param 'cls'
        print "The number of orcs the orc factory has made is", cls.total   

    def __init__ (self):
        Orc.total += 1
        # use self is you want' to register a name
        # however putting a raw_input in an __init__ is NOT recommanded
        # you should pass name as a parameter 
        # and call the raw_input in the for loop
        self.name =  raw_input ("I am a critter by the name of:\n")

orcs = [] # don't call your lists 'list' because `list` is standard Python function

for i in range(4): # put this on two lines for clarity or use a comprehension list
   orcs.append(Orc())  

print "You have created 4 Orcs!" 
print "The name of your first orc is", orcs[0].name # if you don't use `name`, you will see the reference of the object

print "The name of your fourth orc is", orcs[3].name
```

A cleaner version (something you should aim for):

```
class Orc(object):

    total = 0       

    @classmethod # 
    def get_instances_count(cls):
        """
            Return the number or orcs that have been instanciated 
        """
        # ^ Put some documentation below your method
        # these are called "docstring" and are detected by Python

        # you should return values in method rather than print
        # there are rare cases when you do want print, but when you'll
        # encounter them, you won't need me to correct your code anymore
        return cls.total   

    def __init__ (self, name):
        Orc.total += 1
        self.name = name # we get the name as a parameter


l = []

for i in range(4): # put this on two lines for clarity or use a comprehension list
   orc = Orc(raw_input("Enter a name:\n"))
   l.append(orc)  

print "You have created %s Orcs!" % Orc.get_instances_count()
print "The name of your first orc is", l[0].name #

print "The name of your fourth orc is", l[3].name
```

Now the more Pythonic version (something you should be able to do once used to Python):

```
class Orc(object):

    total = 0       

    # you don't need accessors in Python: most things are public anyway
    # and you got property

    def __init__ (self, name):
        Orc.total += 1
        self.name = name # we get the name as a parameter

    def __str__(self):
      # this will be call when printing an orc
      return self.name

# list comprehension are quick and clean ways to create lists
# give a real name to your list
orcs = [Orc(raw_input("Enter a name:\n")) for i in range(4)]

# using parenthesis for `print` is a good habit to take with then incoming Python 3
print("You have created %s Orcs!" % Orc.total)
for i, orc in enumerate(orcs):
  print("Orc #%s is %s" % (i, orc))
```

Comment: -1 Numerous problems -- #1 one probably being that the posted code was never run.

Comment: name of the fourth orc s/b orcs[3].name

Comment: Cool down martineau: first, I write an anwser that solves HIS problem, then, I improve it to make sure it's empty from typo. You do realize I may not be writing this with a Python compiler on my laptop ?

Comment: I really appreciate this detailed answer. Would upvote twice if I could.

Answer (score 3):

`list.append` returns a `None` value, so it essentially never makes sense to assign its result to anything. You call `append` for the side-effects, i.e., to have it put a value at the end of the list. Like this:

```
for i in range (4):    
    list.append(Orc.get_score(Orc()))
```

I don't think the `Orc.get_score(Orc())` is what you want, either: it also returns `None` instead of a score and the method call is technically correct but unlikely to be what you really intend.

Comment: And the reason the OP gets `None` is because `get_score()` doesn't `return` a value.

Comment: @martineau - Oops! I stopped looking at the error with using `append`, because it is such a common one. I'll change the final sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Why should there be something in your list?

you do:

```
list.append(Orc.get_score(Orc())
```

which is equivalent to:

```
item_to_add = Orc.get_score(Orc())
list.append(item_to_add)
```

Your method `Orc.get_score` has no return statement, so it returns `None`. therefore, item_to_add will be None, and None will be appended to your list.

As a side note: python is not java. Dont use classes just to use classes. Use classes, when you want to follow OO-Pradigma, i.e. sending messages to objects.